# how to fetch array value in textbox not working

Tags: cakephp

```
 echo $this->Form->input($mydetails['Mydetails']['specialties'] ,array("type"=>"textarea",'label' => false,'div' => false,'class'=>"umstyle5" ));
```

here $mydetails['Mydetails']['specialties'] have value but text box shows empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the 'value' attribute. The first parameter of the input function is the name of the input not his value

```
echo $this->Form->input(
    'Mydetails.specialties' ,
    array(
        "type"=>"textarea", 
        'label' => false,
        'div' => false,
        'class'=>"umstyle5" , 
        'value' => $mydetails['Mydetails']['specialties']
    )
);
```

Comment: here i changed 'Mydetails.specialties'  to 'specialties' ,its working

Comment: it was justa guess: I cant't know what is the name you want for your input.